# How Do I Load A XNA Model From A File Path Instead Of From The Content (eg. Model.FromStream but it doesnt exist)

Tags: c#, model, xna, load

How do I load an XNA model from a file path instead of from the content (eg. `Model.FromStream` but it doesnt exist)?? `Texture2D` has `.FromStream`, how can I do the equivalent for `Model`?

Comment: Are you talking about a model that is already processed to a .xnb format, or do you mean a .x or .fbx (or other) model? Because unless it's in the xnb format, content.Load<> won't work and it can't become a "Model". If, on the other hand, it is in the xnb format, it would be simplest to direct the content manager to its location and load it normally.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want to use content.Load? That is simply how it works.

Comment: @James You disappoint me :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Content.Load<Model>("Path here, make sure you use drive letter");`

If you really need to have a `FromStream` method on Model you can use extension methods (Not exactly a perfect duplicate of `FromStream` but it should work):

```
public static Model FromPath(this Model model, ContentManager content, string path)
{
    return content.Load<Model>(path);
}
```

EDIT:

I have just tested the above code and apparently, rather than using the drive letter, you need to match the number of `"..\\" in a`reversePath`string with the number of levels of the root directory of the`ContentManager`. The problem is accessing the full directory of the`ContentManager` which is private (or protected, I'm not sure). Short of using reflection I don't think that that variable can be accessed. If we do know the full Root Directory Path then this should work:

```
string reversePath = "";
foreach (string level in Content.FullRootDirectory.Split('\\'))// I know there isn't actually a property 'FullRootDirectory' but for the sake of argument,
{
    reversePath += "..\\";
}
reversePath = reversePath.Substring(4);
```

I've googled a few times and haven't been able to find a way to get the root directory of the ContentManager. I might even ask this as a question here on SO in a bit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696639/how-to-get-the-full-root-directory-of-a-contentmanager-in-xna-4-0).

OK here is the final thing (using the answer from the question linked to above):

1. Add a reference to System.Windows.Forms to your project
2. Add the following code to the top of your Game1.cs file:

   ```
   using System.IO;
   using TApplication = System.Windows.Forms.Application;
   ```
3. Add this code wherever you need it, like in LoadContent or an extension method:

   ```
   string ContentFullPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(TApplication.ExecutablePath),
   Content.RootDirectory);

   string reversePath = "";
   foreach (string level in ContentFullPath.Split('\\'))
   {
       reversePath += "..\\";
   }

   reversePath = reversePath.Substring(3);


   Model test = Content.Load<Model>(Path.Combine(ContentFullPath, reversePath) + "*Your file name here*");
   ```

Comment: Why cant i just do eg. Content.RootDirectory = "C:\\Content"
Also, why is there no Model.FromStream but there is Texture2D.FromStream???????

Comment: Well, I think you might actually be able to do that, if that's what you need then I misunderstood your question. As for why, well you can take that up with Microsoft, but I think it might be because a model file is much more complex than a texture. Also, it has no animation support by default so you need to make a custom content processor or use the skinned model sample for animation.

Comment: Loading a model also loads its materials, which contain effects and textures. Both of these are IDisposable but Model is not, so how do they get cleaned up?  Well its because they are ALSO loaded through the content manager internally when you load a model.